Issue with AWS Lambda, Quarkus App and GraalVM: ClassNotFoundException for QuarkusStreamHandler
I am working on a Quarkus application and compiling it with GraalVM to fix the issue of cold start in AWS. The build process generates a bootstrap.sh file inside a function.zip archive. However, when I upload this zip file to AWS Lambda, I encounter the following error:

{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}

The QuarkusStreamHandler class is part of the basic configuration of the dependency I am using. Here is the relevant dependency from my pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>

Steps :

Compiled the Quarkus app with GraalVM.
Generated the function.zip which contains bootstrap.sh.
Uploaded function.zip to AWS Lambda.
**
Issue Faced:**

AWS Lambda returns a ClassNotFoundException for io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler.
Additional Information:

Quarkus Version: 3.11.0
GraalVM Version: 21 Community version

Question:
How can I resolve this ClassNotFoundException issue? Is there a step I am missing in the build or deployment process? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Have you followed https://quarkus.io/guides/aws-lambda when I create aws lambda example in my local the dependency is quarkus-amazon-lambda not quarkus-amazon-lambda-http
